# Plural vs. Singular and Infinitive vs. Name tags

Tags: discussion, tags, guideline

I see there are several tags that are in a plural form but the singular form would also be acceptable and vice-versa, for examples :

- software
- shortcuts
- applications
- settings
- bookmark

There is the same *problem* for infinitive verbs and the name derivates from this verb :

- printing
- networking
- charging
- mapping
- sharing

As a guideline for the creation of new tags (and why not also edit the current ones) :

### Do tags have to be in a plural or singular form ?

and

### Do tags have to be in an infinitive verb or an -ing name ?

Comment: Why isn't this tagged `[tagging]`?

Comment: If you would like to submit tag corrections, try [Tag corrections](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tag-corrections).

Comment: Uh, what do you mean by using `software` as an example here? "softwares" would be wrong and "a-piece-of-software" would be silly; "software" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an issue with `[printing]`? I would default to looking at [superusers tags](https://superuser.com/tags) to see which seems to be the "correct" tag for this.

Overall I don't think that tags **must** be plural / singular or infinitive as a *general* rule. If you see something tagged `[share]` it should probably be `[sharing]` though.

Answer (score 1):

About **singular vs plural** in cases where both make sense; for example:

- app(s)
- shortcut(s)
- podcast(s)
- accessor(y/ies)
- monitor(s)

I'd say **plural** is good, and that seems to be currently preferred in most cases. However: two observations:

1. In the [top tags](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags) there aren't that many cases where both make sense. (Quickly I found just `monitor` and `passwords` that maybe should be batch-retagged to plural.)
2. We shouldn't get too hung-up with such rule; rather, use what seems the most natural case-by-case.

For the record, plural is what we went with [over at English language & usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags) (where this affects more tags than here).